# How should I trim this door?

Tags: doors, trim

[image: full view]

The above door is set in a double stud wall. On the left side of the door is a skim coated stud that sits about 1" out from the door frame and on the right side the double thick wall sits 4.5" out.  On left, top and right side there is at most 2" of space between the door frame and adjacent wall/ceiling.  What would I use as trim for this door?

Im thinking about just using a 1x4 stained and cut to fit so it will sit flush with the stud on the left and butt up again the ceiling and double thick wall on the right, would that look silly?

**EDIT**

I did some more research and it looks like another option would be to fur out the left and top to be even with the double stud wall and add an extension jamb.  Then, trim the door normally.  What should I know about installing extension jambs?  Should they be flush with the existing jamb or offset?

Left side
[image: left side]

Right side
[image: right side]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Trevor on this statement of his - which was my thought before I read his answer.

"The ultimate solution would have been to bring it all forward so the door was registered to the wall with the light switch, and pad the post on the left to bring the corner out to match. "

After that then I would have simply used dry wall on the interior side of the bathroom to make it look like it was simply a reason for that floor plan - like maybe a pipe was there or the wall had a load bearing beam back there anything to keep it from standing out as an OOPS.

Then it would be just as Trevor said the visual side that will be noticed looks like it should look, and the side that would need tidying up would be hidden for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **as is**, I'd use the trim that matches your other trim in the room around the door. But first I'd drywall tape and mud that stud on the right with a proper corner.

**However,** from the first image it looks like the stud on the left is not vertical with the door, so it will look strange no matter what you do.

The ultimate solution would have been to bring it all forward so the door was registered to the wall with the light switch, and pad the post on the left to bring the corner out to match.

Then do what you have to do on the bathroom side, the side people won't notice so much, to make it as good as you can.

Ultimately, you have to ask yourself... Am I going to be able to stand looking at this for the next N years?

Comment: If I used the same trim that I will use in the rest of the room I'd have to rip it to make it fit in the space which will not look very good.  I understand I could move the door out but I will still have the same problem on the other side (in the bathroom) so my question still stands.  How to trim a door that doesn't have enough room to fit a 2", 3" or 4"+ wide piece of trim.

Comment: Yes I understand that @Preston. Either way you are going to have to improvise. The question is.. do you want it on the side you will look at most often or the side you don't

Comment: It looks like an extension jamb is an option.  I'm going to look into furring out the left side and adding an extension if you have any input on how to go about doing that.

Comment: Place or temporarily nall a couple of 2x4s along the floor so it touches that wall with the switch and extend out past the jam, That will give you your reference line. Mark it with a pencil. Get someone to hold the 2x4 at ceiling level and do the same. Then, remembering to back off the thickness of drywall, use 2x4s to build a new post at the corner and frame across the top.

Comment: Once the framing is done, drywall it and reinstall your door. (WHile doing all that try to take into account what's going to happen on the bathroom side. I cant see in the picture, but you can decide if there ate things you can change there while you are at it.

Comment: YOu can use a chalk like to mark it out instead of a 2x4 too.. If you use the wood..make sure it is straight enough.